# USB mount not working

Tags: usb

Thank you so much in advance.

I tried to mount USB to linux server but keep getting the following message:

"Assuming drive cache: write through"

What is the meaning of the message and how can I correctly mount my external USB drive? Thanks.

Comment: I have never gotten this message, I do not believe this is an error message though. When you try to read/write data on some kind of secondary storage, due to the slowness of the memory, a cache on a faster kind of memory is used to accelerate I/O functions. The write-through policy simply means that any change is written both on the cache and on the device, opposed to the write-back policy which writes data to the storage only when needed.Make sure you have root privileges on the server while mounting devices with `mount` and use `lsblk` to see if the device is correctly detected by the system

Comment: Does this https://askubuntu.com/questions/32107/how-to-avoid-assuming-drive-cache-write-through-message-during-restart answer your questions & follow this for mounting USB https://linuxconfig.org/howto-mount-usb-drive-in-linux